# Surround value in quotes before newline

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm making a jinja2 template to manage SSH keys on some network devices.
I have a dict called `user_info` which is basically `{"username":"ssh_key"}`

For the config to work correctly i need to surround the SSH key in " "
which is easy enough to do in jinja2, like this:

```
system {
    login {
        {% for key, value in user_info.items() %}
        user {{ key }} {
        class super-user; 
        authentication {
            ssh-rsa "{{ value }}"
            }
        }
        {% endfor %}
    }
}
```

note the " " around `{{ value }}`
The issue i'm having is the dict has a newline at the end of the ssh-key for example:

```
'bob': 'ssh-rsa this-is-my-ssk-key\n'
```

so i need to wrap `ssh-rsa this-is-my-ssk-key` in " " but before the new line.

I need to leave the \n in there because some people have multiple ssh-keys and the \n is how it splits them out. e.g.

```
'bob': 'ssh-rsa this-is-my-ssk-key\n ssh-rsa another-ssh-key\n ssh-rsa yes-this-is-one-more-ssh-key'
```

So i need each ssh-rsa section wrapped with " " before the new line...
is this possible?

Comment: split them to list and keep them only as  list. And then you can add `""` to every item and join them back using `'\n'` or you can use `for`-loop in template to display every element separatelly with `"{{ value }}"`

Comment: do you mean split the ssh-keys into a list or the whole thing and not use a dict at all?  Where would i make the split? in jinja2 or my python code?

Comment: Do you want just the first ssh key?

Comment: nah i need all of them

Comment: split only `ssh-rsa` into list and keep this list in your dictionary. Do it in python when you get it.

Comment: Does junos support having multiple SSH keys per user?

Comment: hmm could you provide an example or how to approach that? i'm still learning.  I assume you're talking about a dictionary of lists?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes

Comment: Interesting, do you need to have `ssh-rsa "key"` on a new line for every key?

Comment: Or do you need `ssh-rsa "key1" "key2" "key3"`?

Comment: they all go on a new line for each key

Answer (score 1):

Try this if they all need to go on their own line. `.strip()` will remove any trailing newlines before splitting

```
authentication {
    {% for key in value.strip().split('\n') %}
        ssh-rsa "{{ key }}"
    {% endfor %}
}
```